# React Native iOS - Location of .ipa file

Tags: ios, react-native

Where to find the generated `.ipa` file?

What I did:

1. Run the command `react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios`
2. Then followed by `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`

Now where will I find the `.ipa` file and install on a physical iPhone device?

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to use xcode to build the ipa for you. This can be done using the command-line `xcodebuild` tool using the following in the ios project folder.
First, create the app archive:

> xcodebuild -workspace *YourWorkspaceFile* -scheme *YourSchemeAsInXcode* -configuration *Release* -archivePath *SomewhereEasyForYouToFind/someFilename.xcarchive* archive

Next, build the .ipa:

> xcodebuild  -archivePath *SomewhereEasyForYouToFind/someFilename.xcarchive* -exportOptionsPlist *YourExport.plist* -exportPath *SomewhereEasyForYouToFind/someFilename*

For the format of the `export.plist`file, refer to the help of the `xcodebuild` tool.